# Opamp design using LTspice

Tags: integrated-circuit, ltspice, analog-switch

I just finished an online lecture about analog IC design. I want to put into practice what I have learned and searched for projects that will help me achieve my goal. I stumbled upon this project online

[image]

In the lecture that I watched online the parameter KP = Un*Cox is always given. In the project shown above, there is a model of the device that be can used for the design using LTspice, my question is how do I determine the value of KP from the model provided? Thank you!

The MODEL:

````
* BSIM3 models for AMI Semiconductor's C5 process
*
* Don't forget the .options scale=300nm if using drawn lengths
* and the MOSIS SUBM design rules
*
* 2<Ldrawn<500   10<Wdrawn<10000 Vdd=5V
* Note minimum L is 0.6 um while minimum W is 3 um
* Change to level=49 when using HSPICE or SmartSpice

.MODEL NMOS NMOS (                                 LEVEL   = 8
+VERSION = 3.1            TNOM    = 27             TOX     = 1.39E-8
+XJ      = 1.5E-7         NCH     = 1.7E17         VTH0    = 0.6696061
+K1      = 0.8351612      K2      = -0.0839158     K3      = 23.1023856
+K3B     = -7.6841108     W0      = 1E-8           NLX     = 1E-9
+DVT0W   = 0              DVT1W   = 0              DVT2W   = 0
+DVT0    = 2.9047241      DVT1    = 0.4302695      DVT2    = -0.134857
+U0      = 458.439679     UA      = 1E-13          UB      = 1.485499E-18
+UC      = 1.629939E-11   VSAT    = 1.643993E5     A0      = 0.6103537
+AGS     = 0.1194608      B0      = 2.674756E-6    B1      = 5E-6
+KETA    = -2.640681E-3   A1      = 8.219585E-5    A2      = 0.3564792
+RDSW    = 1.387108E3     PRWG    = 0.0299916      PRWB    = 0.0363981
+WR      = 1              WINT    = 2.472348E-7    LINT    = 3.597605E-8
+XL      = 0              XW      = 0              DWG     = -1.287163E-8
+DWB     = 5.306586E-8    VOFF    = 0              NFACTOR = 0.8365585
+CIT     = 0              CDSC    = 2.4E-4         CDSCD   = 0
+CDSCB   = 0              ETA0    = 0.0246738      ETAB    = -1.406123E-3
+DSUB    = 0.2543458      PCLM    = 2.5945188      PDIBLC1 = -0.4282336
+PDIBLC2 = 2.311743E-3    PDIBLCB = -0.0272914     DROUT   = 0.7283566
+PSCBE1  = 5.598623E8     PSCBE2  = 5.461645E-5    PVAG    = 0
+DELTA   = 0.01           RSH     = 81.8           MOBMOD  = 1
+PRT     = 8.621          UTE     = -1             KT1     = -0.2501
+KT1L    = -2.58E-9       KT2     = 0              UA1     = 5.4E-10
+UB1     = -4.8E-19       UC1     = -7.5E-11       AT      = 1E5
+WL      = 0              WLN     = 1              WW      = 0
+WWN     = 1              WWL     = 0              LL      = 0
+LLN     = 1              LW      = 0              LWN     = 1
+LWL     = 0              CAPMOD  = 2              XPART   = 0.5
+CGDO    = 2E-10          CGSO    = 2E-10          CGBO    = 1E-9
+CJ      = 4.197772E-4    PB      = 0.99           MJ      = 0.4515044
+CJSW    = 3.242724E-10   PBSW    = 0.1            MJSW    = 0.1153991
+CJSWG   = 1.64E-10       PBSWG   = 0.1            MJSWG   = 0.1153991
+CF      = 0              PVTH0   = 0.0585501      PRDSW   = 133.285505
+PK2     = -0.0299638     WKETA   = -0.0248758     LKETA   = 1.173187E-3
+AF      = 1              KF      = 0)
*
.MODEL PMOS PMOS (                                 LEVEL   = 8
+VERSION = 3.1            TNOM    = 27             TOX     = 1.39E-8
+XJ      = 1.5E-7         NCH     = 1.7E17         VTH0    = -0.9214347
+K1      = 0.5553722      K2      = 8.763328E-3    K3      = 6.3063558
+K3B     = -0.6487362     W0      = 1.280703E-8    NLX     = 2.593997E-8
+DVT0W   = 0              DVT1W   = 0              DVT2W   = 0
+DVT0    = 2.5131165      DVT1    = 0.5480536      DVT2    = -0.1186489
+U0      = 212.0166131    UA      = 2.807115E-9    UB      = 1E-21
+UC      = -5.82128E-11   VSAT    = 1.713601E5     A0      = 0.8430019
+AGS     = 0.1328608      B0      = 7.117912E-7    B1      = 5E-6
+KETA    = -3.674859E-3   A1      = 4.77502E-5     A2      = 0.3
+RDSW    = 2.837206E3     PRWG    = -0.0363908     PRWB    = -1.016722E-5
+WR      = 1              WINT    = 2.838038E-7    LINT    = 5.528807E-8
+XL      = 0              XW      = 0              DWG     = -1.606385E-8
+DWB     = 2.266386E-8    VOFF    = -0.0558512     NFACTOR = 0.9342488
+CIT     = 0              CDSC    = 2.4E-4         CDSCD   = 0
+CDSCB   = 0              ETA0    = 0.3251882      ETAB    = -0.0580325
+DSUB    = 1              PCLM    = 2.2409567      PDIBLC1 = 0.0411445
+PDIBLC2 = 3.355575E-3    PDIBLCB = -0.0551797     DROUT   = 0.2036901
+PSCBE1  = 6.44809E9      PSCBE2  = 6.300848E-10   PVAG    = 0
+DELTA   = 0.01           RSH     = 101.6          MOBMOD  = 1
+PRT     = 59.494         UTE     = -1             KT1     = -0.2942
+KT1L    = 1.68E-9        KT2     = 0              UA1     = 4.5E-9
+UB1     = -6.3E-18       UC1     = -1E-10         AT      = 1E3
+WL      = 0              WLN     = 1              WW      = 0
+WWN     = 1              WWL     = 0              LL      = 0
+LLN     = 1              LW      = 0              LWN     = 1
+LWL     = 0              CAPMOD  = 2              XPART   = 0.5
+CGDO    = 2.9E-10        CGSO    = 2.9E-10        CGBO    = 1E-9
+CJ      = 7.235528E-4    PB      = 0.9527355      MJ      = 0.4955293
+CJSW    = 2.692786E-10   PBSW    = 0.99           MJSW    = 0.2958392
+CJSWG   = 6.4E-11        PBSWG   = 0.99           MJSWG   = 0.2958392
+CF      = 0              PVTH0   = 5.98016E-3     PRDSW   = 14.8598424
+PK2     = 3.73981E-3     WKETA   = 5.292165E-3    LKETA   = -4.205905E-3 
+AF      = 1              KF      = 0)
```
````

Comment: You need to share "the model provided" if you want us to be able to answer a question about it.

Comment: I had the same problem with several other questions this week.  They hint at things with vague screenshots instead of simply providing the link, so I have to do a bunch of unnecessary detective work: http://www.cmosedu.com/jbaker/courses/ee420_ecg620/s19/hw_ee420_ecg620.htm

Comment: *how do I determine the value of KP* What if I gave you an N-channel MOSFET, I tell you that the N-channel MOSFET has a W/L of 100. You have all the voltage and current supplies and multimeters that you need available to you. How would you determine the \$K_P\$ of that MOSFET? Now do the same in the simulator.

Comment: I followed @SteKulov's link and ogled some of the lecture notes. No idea what you understood from there, but in several places I saw formulas for dimensioning of the transistors, and the likes. So it looks like you should be able to do that yourself from your course notes.

Comment: I know the formula for Id which contains KP, but from what I encountered KP is always given. How do I determine the KP of the model using LTspice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, KP is explicitly used only with the simpler MOSFET models, such as the Shichman-Hodges model (i.e. LEVEL 1).  The BSIM3 model (LEVEL 8) is much more sophisticated and typically defined using geometrical/physical parameters instead of electrical parameters.  Although the idea of KP still exists in BSIM3, it's heavily modified by many more parameters so it's rarely used on its own.  Anyway, if you start with the basic equation you referenced, you can expand it further as such:
$$
\text{KP} = \mu_0 \cdot C_{ox}' = \mu_0 \cdot \frac{\varepsilon_{ox}}{t_{ox}} = \mu_0 \cdot \frac{\varepsilon_r \varepsilon_0}{t_{ox}}
$$

where

\$\text{KP}\$ is the transconductance parameter,

\$\mu_0\$ is the surface mobility,

\$C_{ox}'\$ is the capacitance per unit area of the oxide layer,

\$\varepsilon_{ox}\$ is the permittivity of the oxide,

\$t_{ox}\$ is the oxide thickness,

\$\varepsilon_r\$ is the dielectric constant of the oxide material, and

\$\varepsilon_0\$ is the permittivity of free space (\$8.85 \times 10^{-14} \text{F/cm}\$).

---

I will only focus on the NMOS here, and you can do the PMOS on your own using the same math.  \$\mu_0\$ is already defined in the model as `U0 = 458.439679`.  The same goes for \$t_{ox}\$ where `TOX = 1.39E-8`, except it's specified in meters and needs to be converted to centimeters since \$\mu_0\$ and \$\varepsilon_0\$ are specified in centimeters.  I don't know enough about IC design, so I'm going to assume SiO<sub>2</sub> (silicon dioxide) as the oxide material for this example which has a dielectric constant of `3.9`.  Using these numbers along with the constant \$\varepsilon_0\$  defined above, we get:

$$
\text{KP} = \mu_0 \cdot \frac{\varepsilon_r \varepsilon_0}{t_{ox}} = 458.439679 \frac{\text{cm}^2}{\text{V} \cdot \text{s}} \cdot \frac{3.9 \cdot (8.85 \times 10^{-14} \text{F/cm})}{(1.39 \times 10^{-6} \text{cm})} \approx 113.835 \times 10^{-6} \frac{\text{A}}{\text{V}^2}
$$

---

The following are the two references I used to create this answer.  I suggest at least skimming through the BSIM3 reference since that is what is being used as the basis for validating this project via SPICE.

- http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/external-documents/models/bsim330_manual.pdf
- https://books.google.com/books/about/Semiconductor_Device_Modeling_with_SPICE.html?id=_QZTAAAAMAAJ

*EDIT1: I forgot to include the units, and hence made an error in the calculation from lack of converting the units.  I added the units and fixed the calculation.*

---

*EDIT2: I was asked to go into details on how to extract KP from measurement of simulation results using SPICE, so I added these extra sections below.  Keep in mind that the premise here is somewhat strange, because we're using results generated from a LEVEL 8 model (BSIM3) to map back onto LEVEL 1 model parameters.*

The first thing to know is that there are two separate test setups since MOSFETs can be operated in the linear and saturation regions.  Each setup corresponds to each region and the resultant KP between the two will be slightly different.  I will present both methods, but it's recommended that only one be used based on the desired application and operating mode for the MOSFET.  To begin, the basic LEVEL 1 model equations are shown below.
$$
\begin{align*} 
&\text{Linear: } &&I_{DS} = \text{KP} \frac{W}{L-2 \text{LD}} \left( V_{GS}-V_{TH}-\frac{V_{DS}}{2} \right) V_{DS}(1 + \lambda V_{DS}) \\ \\
&\text{Saturation: } &&I_{DS} = \frac{\text{KP}}{2} \frac{W}{L-2 \text{LD}} (V_{GS}-V_{TH})^2 (1 + \lambda V_{DS})
\end{align*}
$$
Now, a few simplifications can be made.  Based on how we set up the linear region test, \$\frac{V_{DS}}{2}\$ will be negligible so that can be set to zero. \$\lambda\$ is the channel-length modulation which we can assume to be zero as well.  To further simplify, we need to set \$\frac{W}{L-2 \text{LD}}\$ to 1.  LD is the "lateral diffusion" parameter and is basically a fixed correction offset applied to \$L\$.  If we make the MOSFET long enough then LD is negligible.  Assuming LD is usually 1µm or less, we set `L=100u` and `W=100u` (to match) and are left with:
$$
\begin{align*} 
&\text{Linear: } &&I_{DS} = \text{KP} \cdot V_{DS} (V_{GS}-V_{TH}) \\ \\
&\text{Saturation: } &&I_{DS} = \frac{\text{KP}}{2} (V_{GS}-V_{TH})^2
\end{align*}
$$
What this says for the linear region is that if we sweep \$V_{GS}\$ for a fixed \$V_{DS}\$ and plot \$I_{DS}\$, then its slope divided by \$V_{DS}\$ equals KP.  For the saturation region we can do something similar, but need to first take the square-root of \$I_{DS}\$ before finding the slope and solving for KP. Mathematically, in each scenario:
$$
\begin{align*} 
&\text{Linear: } &&\frac{dI_{DS}}{dV_{GS}} = \text{KP} \cdot V_{DS} \implies \text{KP} = \frac{dI_{DS}}{dV_{GS}} \cdot \frac{1}{V_{DS}} \\ \\
&\text{Saturation: } &&\frac{d\sqrt{I_{DS}}}{dV_{GS}} = \sqrt{\frac{\text{KP}}{2}} \implies \text{KP} = 2 \left( \frac{d\sqrt{I_{DS}}}{dV_{GS}} \right)^2
\end{align*}
$$

---

The test setups are shown below.  M1 is the MOSFET for the linear region test and M2 is for the saturation region test.  The only difference between the two is that \$V_{DS}\$ is set to a small fixed value of 50mV in the linear test, while \$V_{DS}\$ is shorted to \$V_{GS}\$ for the saturation test.  We will sweep \$V_{GS}\$ from 1mV to 5V in 1mV steps.  [NOTE: Starting at 1mV instead of zero avoids a divide-by-zero artifact when using LTspice to do the KP calculations.]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first plot is the \$I_{DS}\$ of M1.  The idea is to use the slope value right after the threshold voltage where the plot first appears linear.  This avoids the weak inversion region while also avoiding errors in the later regions due to series resistance.  I selected points at 1.0V and 1.1V and divided this slope by 50m (our \$V_{DS}\$) to get:
$$
\text{KP(lin)} = \frac{6.10144 \times 10^{-6}}{50 \times 10^{-3}} \approx 122.029 \times 10^{-6} \frac{\text{A}}{\text{V}^2}
$$
The second plot is the square-root of \$I_{DS}\$ of M2.  I picked the same voltage points of 1.0V and 1.1V to get the slope.  This slope is squared and then multiplied by two to get KP:
$$
\text{KP(sat)} = 2 \cdot (7.44373 \times 10^{-3})^2 \approx 110.818 \times 10^{-6} \frac{\text{A}}{\text{V}^2}
$$

The last thing I want to mention is that you can also use LTspice's waveform mathematics feature to have it plot KP across all \$V_{GS}\$.  You simply need to plug in the above equations as shown below.  The reason I wanted to show these plots is to highlight that KP is not constant in a real MOSFET, and is one of the reasons the higher level MOSFET models were developed.  If you performed the same KP extraction procedures on a LEVEL 1 model instead of a LEVEL 8, these plots would look quite different.

[image]

Comment: thank you! Is there a way we can do this in simulation? The professor said in a lecture that KP can be determined from a plot. I am assume a plot from LTspice. I just don't know to set it up. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: You can, but I didn't realize that's what you were asking.  One thing to be careful of is that the standard extraction procedures assume simplified models.  The result might be close enough for what you want to do, but it's something to be mindful of.  Another thing to be careful of is that the extraction procedure is different between operating in the linear region vs the saturated region.

Comment: Could you guide on to properly set up the extraction process in LTspice. I did what the other members told me but the result is not even close to what you have hand calculated. Thank you!

Comment: @Paumdrdo Sure, I'll give it a shot and edit the answer once more.

Comment: @Paumdrdo OK, it took longer than I thought, but I added a comprehensive guide on how to extract KP.  Hopefully it's helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna try this to PMOS! Thank you! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I have used example model card for this simulation. Blue plot will give you kp value which was used in the model card.

This plot is input characteristics of the MOSFET. Rearranging the Id equation for kp.

Hope this helps for the model you have provided.

Comment: Hello Pai What's the difference of the green and blue plot? What do you mean by "with vt' and "without vt'?

Comment: I had missed to remove experimented plots.I have updated the answer

Comment: What you mean by without vt though?

Comment: @Paumdrdo without means i haven't used default vtho of the simulator ( Inserted Vtho as 0.7 to the formula in waveform but didn't extract from the model card )

Comment: Hello Pai can you check my setup? Is it correct? It seems to small for a KP value.

Comment: @Paumdrdo I have used W = 2u and L =1u. This might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Can someone check if the result I have is reasonble value of KP thank you!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also this link will help if you consider the channel length modulation parameter
[http://www.ece.tamu.edu/~spalermo/ecen474/Lab1.pdf](http://www.ece.tamu.edu/%7Espalermo/ecen474/Lab1.pdf)