# MOS transconductance plot using LTspice

Tags: ltspice, cmos, transconductance

I am trying to plot the transconductance of a MOS using LTspice in DC sweep. However, I heard that there is no dy/dx function in LTspice. Therefore, I came up with another way.

Keep the drain voltage fix, DC sweep the gate voltage, this MOS is M1. I can get a plot of drain_current to gate_voltage.

Than I draw a almost identical circuit, using behavioral voltage source at the second MOS's gate, M2, the BV source is set 1mV higher than the first MOS.

Using another behavioral voltage source, ploting [i(v2)-i(v4)]/1mV, I can get the mos transconductance versus current and gate voltage.
[image]
Is there a better, easier, and more accurate way to do this?

Comment: Is what you're calling "transconductance" the same as the KP parameter?  If so, I show a procedure here:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/528631

Comment: You can also simplify your approach by getting rid of both behavioral sources.  The 2nd one is completely useless since you can directly plot the expression you want using [waveform arithmetic](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelpXVII/LTspiceHelp/html/Waveform_Arithmetic.htm).  For the first one, you should just route your Vgs sweep voltage to both gates and add a 1mV offset to the 2nd gate, like shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YaCz.png

Comment: @SteKulov thank you. the "transconductance" I mentioned is simply the gate-voltage-to-drain-current ratio, gm, not Kp. I didn't know "waveform arithmetic" before. According to the LTwiki link you provide, there is a function d( ), difference base derivative, seems like I can plot the transconductance gm using this directly. No second MOS needed. Thank you sir, very helpful answer.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. I also use the `d()` function in the answer I linked (at the very end). The LTwiki link is just a copy of the built-in LTspice help. Press F1 key to pull up the Help whenever you need it.